# Confused about single displacement Reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

This question is about predicting reactions

Al(s) + FeO(s) ---> no reaction

Al is higher on the activity series so why does it result in no reaction instead of replacing Fe?

Comment: Once initiated there will be a thermite reaction.

Comment: Note that, generally, metal reactivity serie relates to electrochemical potentials in water environment and is just indirectly related to outcome of water free reactions between solids. Saying that, I agree with the prior comment.

Comment: I don't understand the premise of the second statement. If a metal is higher on the activity series, it should be more likely to lose electrons...

Answer (score 5):

Although the electrode potential of the reaction:

$$\ce{2Al(s) + 3 Fe^2+(aq) -> 2Al^3+(aq) + 3 Fe (s) }$$

is favorable (E<sup>0</sup> = +1.21 V), which is what I am assuming you are referring to, it does not apply in this instance as it takes place in aqueous solution. Although the reaction of *solid* aluminum with *solid* ferrous oxide is thermodynamically favorable, it is not kinetically favorable. The Fe<sup>2+</sup> ions are locked in a lattice with O<sup>2-</sup> ions, and solid aluminum normally has a protective oxide coating on it that prevents it from oxidation. However, because the reaction is thermodynamically favorable, it will actually proceed at a very slow rate (but only if the aluminum oxide layer is removed). This rate is almost impossible to detect, and there is no reaction for all intents and purposes.

When in aqueous solution, Fe<sup>2+</sup> ions could technically be formed and the above equation could apply in this case; however, this will not occur in this situation as FeO is insoluble in water. If the ferrous salt used instead was soluble, such as FeCl<sub>2</sub>, then the reaction could occur in aqueous solution, and iron will precipitate out of solution.

The only way for the reaction to take place with the given states of matter is for a thermite reaction to take place:

$$\ce{2Al(s) + 3 FeO(s) -> Al2O3(s) + 3 Fe (s) }$$

However, the only way for this to occur is for the reaction system to be ignited, which is not a given condition in your equation.